# Slicing certain elements of a tuple

Tags: python, slice

If I have tuple:

```
myT=(“a”, “b”, “c”, “d”, “e”, “f”)
```

Is it possible to slice out say `“a”, “d”, “e”`?

Something like `myT = myT[0, 3, 4]`.

Comment: Not with Python, no.  Numpy can do that with its array types.  You can, of course, say `myT = tuple( n for i,n in enumerate(myT) if i in (0,3,4))`.

Comment: `myT[0, 3, 4]` isn't a slice. Are you actually looking for a slice, or just any indexing? Why not use `myT[0], myT[3], myT[4]`?

Comment: @Tim Simpler: `tuple(myT[i] for i in (0,3,4))`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a standard concise way to write something like that.

What you can do is:

```
a = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f')
b = (a[0], a[3], a[4])
```

Or, if you don't want to refer to `a` more than once, the simplest option should be something like this:

```
b = tuple(a[x] for x in [0, 3, 4])
```

But if you find that you need this in multiple places, you can consider writing a utility function.

Comment: That's not a slice. If this is an alternative suggestion, please say so. See [answer]: *'What is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or at least a viable alternative. Your answer can say “don’t do that,” but it should also say “try this instead.” '*

Answer (score 0):

`operator.itemgetter` could be worth a try. At least it looks quite similar to what you're asking for:

```py
from operator import itemgetter

myT = tuple("abcdef")

# ('a', 'd', 'e')
print(itemgetter(0,3,4)(myT))
```